# Android: TargetFrameworkVersion is greater than my project

Tags: android, xamarin.android, target-framework

At the moment, I have installed some packages from nuget. I realized there are warning saying the target framework is greater than my setting in my project. When I ran my application, the application still running. Do I have to change my target framework as the packages required. If I leave it as it is, will my project still ok.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin Studio?

Comment: Good Guess. Yes I am

Comment: So you should mention it so that Xamarin android developers may be able to help you out. For your warning AFAIK, sometimes it may lead to build failures

Comment: I thought this question also part of android environment too. If my device was running KitKat but the application was targetFramework set to greater than kitkat. Will it still running the application on my device.

Comment: It may not run because since the target framework is greater it may use some features which your device does not support

Comment: Do you know any library similar to Picasso but work on KitKat coz I am currently running KitKat.

Comment: I don't actively work with Xamarin.Android so I can't give you much information but I think Picasso will have support for KitKat. You can also have a look at https://components.xamarin.com/view/urlimageviewhelper and https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Answer (score 1):

Late to the show but I fixed this cleaning a couple of cs files from the temp folder in:

```
..\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Temp\
```

one of those will be `MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs`